# read a large file without memory reallocation

Tags: python, memory

When I want to read a binary file in memory in python I just do:

```
with open("file.bin","rb") as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

With "reasonable" size files, it's perfect, but when the files are huge (say, 1Gb or more), when monitoring the process, we notice that the memory increases then shrinks, then increases, ... probably the effect of `realloc` behind the scenes, when the original chunk of memory is too small to hold the file.

Done several times, this `realloc` + `memmove` operation takes a lot of CPU time. In C, I wouldn't have the problem because I would pass a properly allocated buffer to `fread` for instance (but here I can't because `bytes` objects are immutable, so I cannot pre-allocate).

Of course I could read it chunk by chunk like this:

```
with open("file.bin","rb") as f:
    while True:
        contents = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        if contents:
            chunks.append(contents)
        else:
             break
```

but then I would have to `join` the bytes chunks, but that would also take twice the needed memory at some point, and I may not be able to afford it.

Is there a method to read a big binary file in a buffer with one sole big memory allocation, and efficiently CPU-wise?

Comment: Have you read this answer by Alex? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1288382/2867928 Using `mmap` might be a good option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `os.open` method, which is basically a wrapper around the POSIX syscall `open`.

```
import os
fd = os.open("file.bin", os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY)
```

This opens the file in `rb` mode.

`os.open` returns a file descriptor which does not have `read` methods. You'll have to read `n` bytes at a time:

```
data = os.read(fd, 100)
```

Once done, use `os.close` to close the file:

```
os.close(fd)
```

You're reading a file in Python just like you'd do it in C!

Here's a couple of useful references:

1. [Official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open)
2. [Library Reference](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/os-fd-ops.html)

Disclaimer: Based on my knowledge of how C's `open` function works, I believe this *should* do the trick.

Comment: Typo: It's `O_BINARY`. My bad.

Comment: nice. so I could do `os.read(fd,os.path.getsize(filename))` to read it fully in one go. Let me test this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what'd happen if you read it at one go. But it's worth a shot.

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected, let me know and I'll delete my answer. :)